# Simple Excel Lookup not returning correct answer

Tags: excel

```
       A                    B        C                  D
1      listing_region    region_id   region-name        regioncode
2      Auckland             1        Northland          0
3      Waikato/Waitomo      7        Auckland           1
4      Waikato/Waitomo      7        Waikato/Waitomo    2
5      Waikato/Waitomo      7        Bay of Plenty      3
6      Waikato/Waitomo      7        The Lakes District 4
7      Waikato/Waitomo      7        Hawkes Bay         5
8      Waikato/Waitomo      7        Manawatu           6
9      Waikato/Waitomo      7        Taranaki           7
10     Waikato/Waitomo      7        Wairarapa          8
11     Bay of Plenty        1        Wellington         9
```

Hi there! I am using a very simple Lookup function in excel to match a value in a cell with a column of values and return the corresponding value.

For instance, the formula I used for cell B3 is `=LOOKUP(A3,$C$2:$C$11,$D$2:$D$11)`
And I was expecting the value of D4 be returned, which should be 2. However, I got 7, which corresponds with the region "Taranaki".

I also tried VLOOKUP function and still I got the same result.

Could you please help me on this very simple lookup function?

Thanks in advance.

[excel lookup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyk76.png)

Answer (score 1):

Why did you get the wrong answer?

For LOOKUP to work as expected data must be [sorted](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/lookup-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb?ocmsassetID=HP010342671&CorrelationId=f1d6ebc9-3adb-439a-955b-b3128f7a27ed&ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB) by column C ascending.

[image]

---

You could also use Index and  Match:

Columns C and D are your lookup table. You want to match `listing_region` against `region_name` (in column C) and retrieve the value from column D in the same row. You can use `MATCH` to find the row where the match is and `INDEX` retrieve the matching row number value from column D. Wrap the whole thing in `IFERROR` in case no match found.

So, in B2 and drag down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$11,MATCH(A2,$C$2:$C$11,0)),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a great example of why you should not use `VLOOKUP` ever again.  Start using `INDEX/MATCH` and a lot of your problems will disappear.  Reading about [why VLOOKUP sucks](https://medium.com/@cbenkendorf/why-excel-vlookup-sucks-and-what-to-use-instead-3d82e697512)  will change your life forever.

[image]